# Error received while importing the backup from Jira 4.4.5 to Jira 5.2?

Tags: jira

We are plannning to upgrade the Jira from 4.0 to 7x, So, the plan is to pass the bacup file through all the intermidate major version of Jira and finally import it to Jira 7. We were sucessfully imported the data from Jira 4.0 to Jira 4.4.5 but while importing the backup of Jira 4.4.5 to jira 52. we received the below error which has blocked us. Can someone help, Thanks in Advance.
Error parsing export file. Your export file is invalid. This may be due to a CDATA bug in older versions of JIRA (http://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-4980). Exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; Attribute name "ent" associated with an element type "UserHistoryItem" must be followed by the '=" character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per mentioned in their KB, you need to download Atlassian XML Cleaner JAR file and clean up your XML backup prior to import. I would recommend you to take a look at full steps in [this KB](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/removing-invalid-characters-from-xml-backups-12079.html).